# how to use sender arg for access to i&j in 2D Array in C#?

Tags: c#

i have a code like this:

```
Label[,] Cell = new Label[8, 8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {    
        Cell[i, j] = new Label();
        Cell[i, j].Text = (i + 1) + "" + (j + 1);
        Cell[i, j].Location = new Point(j * 50 + 25, i * 50 + 25);
        this.Controls.Add(Cell[i, j]);                    
        Cell[i, j].Click += new System.EventHandler(lbl_click);
    }
}

public void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//I want having i & j here and work with them.
}
```

How can I access `i` and `j` variables from within the click event handler?

Comment: short answer, you can't. The sender (label itself) doesnt know about it's positon in the array

Comment: The sender will be the `Label` that raised the event.  You should be able to get the index values by parsing the `Text` of the `Label` assuming that nothing else changes that.

Comment: Why not? If the text of the label is i+1 & j+1, he could split the text of the label, convert the strings to int and substract 1?

Comment: Or `Tag` the label with the data (as a class, array, whetever...)

Comment: then What should I do?

Comment: What do you need the indexes for?  If it's to access the Label in the array then just cast the sender object.

Comment: @Serv : that is a brilliant idea! thanks

Comment: @juharr : i want work with i&j, Serv's idea is nice.

Comment: Just a question: Why do you store the labels in an array? Your code doesn't show any use of that array, do you use it later in the function? It doesn't appear to have any use as your code stands

Comment: because i want to use i&j of label in function

Answer (score 4):

**Using the Tag property**

One option could be to `Tag` the label with the data you need to use.

For example, create a class to hold the data...

```
class TagData
{
    public int I { get; set; }
    public int J { get; set; }
}
```

In your loop...

```
Cell[i, j].Tag = new TagData() { I = i, J = j };
```

In the event handler...

```
public void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;
    TagData tagData = label.Tag as TagData;

    // Do something with tagData.I and tagData.J
}
```

---

**Parsing the label Text**

If you can assume that neither `i` or `j` would be more than a single digit each, then you could simply parse the `Text`. Like so:

```
public void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;
    int i = int.Parse(label.Text[0]) - 1;
    int j = int.Parse(label.Text[1]) - 1;
}
```

NOTE: The danger with more than a single digit for each is that without a separator you could not know if `"123"` was `i = 1` or `i = 12`. You could of course work around this by using a separator, for example `"12,3"` but I wouldn't suggest having code that relies on specific UI design/formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to  musefan here is the solution with storing the coordinates in the Tag of the label. Winforms controls got a Property called Tag where you can store related Information.

```
Label[,] Cell = new Label[8, 8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {    
                Label tempLabel = new Label();
                Cell[i,j] = tempLabel;
                tempLabel.Text = (i + 1) + "" + (j + 1);
                tempLabel.Location = new Point(j * 50 + 25, i * 50 + 25);
                tempLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(lbl_click);
                tempLabel.Tag = new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
                this.Controls.Add(tempLabel);
            }
    }
public void lbl_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             Label label = sender as Label;
             Tuple<int, int> position = label.Tag as Tuple<int, int>;
             if(positon != null)
             {
                 int i = position.Item1;
                 int j = position.Item2;
                 //do whatever with the coordinates
             }

    }
```